How to override Equals and HashCode in protocoal buffer java generated classes
e.g.message
Example {    
   string name = 1;    
   int32 color = 2;    
   int32 icon = 3;  
}

If equals() and hashCode() in java depend only on name field and not on all the fields.
How to implement this in protoc generated java classes when using protocol Buffer in java?

In protoc? what is it?

@Elikill58 protoc is the Protocol Buffers compiler which compiles protobuf code and generates an equivalent Java class file. The OP is asking how to implement custom equals and hashcode methods for classes that are generated by protoc.

Your question would benefit from more clarity around what you mean.
My assumption (!) is that the protoc-generated classes define equals and hashCode for all fields (name,color and icon) in the message but you want to redefine these messages using the name field only.
The best way to do this is to define a wrapper classes for the protoc-generated classes that defines equals, hashCode and any other methods you want.
You are encouraged to not redefine the protoc-generated code.

Yes. It is better to create a new Object with equals /hashcode rather that change protoc.exe generated classes.
